# retrieve data from sqlite, diplays the name colums in a textview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, textview

I have a database in sqlite I am trying to display the  name columns of the login table  in a textview or a listiew.

In the **databeaseHAndler** class I used HashMap to select all users from  the table, but  I don't know how to get the result of that query to show in a textview(if it's possible using ashmap) or a Listview.

Ideally they should only be one record in the table, which is why I wanted it to show up in a textview, to basically display the user that's logged into my app. Does any know how to do this?

My **Databasehandler** class:

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "u168512214_barzd";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }





 /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }
```

The HomeFragment class Where I want to diplay the name on :

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {
TextView username;
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnViewBars;
Button btnNewBar;
private DatabaseHandler userDetails;

AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameList;
```

// Session Manager Class
    //SessionManager session;

```
public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
                   btnViewBars = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewBars);
          btnNewBar = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateBar);


          nameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String, String> user = userDetails.getUserDetails();
```

edit:

```
    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
         Log.i("key_ID","value is: " + cursor.getString(0));

             Log.i("key_name","value is: " + cursor.getString(1));

             Log.i("key_email","value is: " + cursor.getString(2));
             Log.i("key_uid","value is: " + cursor.getString(3));
             Log.i("key_created_at","value is: " + cursor.getString(4));
           //user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));

//            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
//            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
//            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create object of your databaseHandler class

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
```

Now, get list of users in hash map

```
HashMap<String, String> user=db.getUserDetails();
```

noe iterate through hashmap size i.e. use a loop condition and get values from hash map and set on your text view

```
user.get(i).get("name")
```

Comment: I have just tried it now it say method 'get(textView)' is undefined for the type string

Comment: please post your updated code here "name" is the key you have used while creating hashmap in database class  user.put("name", cursor.getString(1)); use the correct key to retreive value

Comment: ` db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
               HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

               while(i>0){
               
               user.get(i).get("name");
               
               }' it returns i cannot b resolved as a variable, and how do i set it to my texview???

Comment: ` db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity()); HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails(); while(i>0){ user.get(i).get("name"); }`it returns i cannot b resolved as a variable, and how do i set it to my texview???

Comment: you have to initialize i with o and loop till size of your hashmap like for(int i=0; i<user.size();i++){tv.settext(user.get(i).get("name"));}

Comment: `get(name)`the get(String) is undefined for the type string. could it be because I already pass a string when i do get(i). not sure how what data type to pass

Comment: sorry but i am not getting your problem, can you post your code and log cat... het in user.get(i).get("name") - i should be integer, it denotes index of hashmap you want to access and name is your key you had use in database class to store values

Comment: my code : db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
              
              HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
         

              for( int i=0; i<user.size();i++){
               username.settext(user.get(i).get("name"));
               }

Comment: I cant run the program because I get an error at the Get("name") the get is underlined in red not the name . and it says:The method get(String) is undefined for the type String

Comment: and  i added my edited  seclt from db code with log.e in my question

Comment: ohk.. just try user.get(i) or user.get("name")

Comment: I tried:  `lblName.setText( user.get("name"));` and I tried `username.setText(user.get(i));` on both them the error disappeared but it doesn't populate the username

Comment: I figured it out   I put it inside a string this way, it was so simple thanks, but I could see the result before because i was using the log.i which instead of user.put  `for( int i=0; i<user.size();i++){
  String userReturned = user.get("name");
  lblName.setText(userReturned);`